# How could you safely break onto a space shuttle?

Tags: spacecraft

Writing a near-future SF novel here. One character has to rescue another character from an enemy space shuttle (in orbit). Most hull breach scenarios sound really dangerous-- is there a method that would be non-catastrophic? Somehow containing the breach, or surrounding the shuttle with a giant bag before breaching it?

Comment: This might be a better fit at worldbuilding.stackexchange. (I might be wrong)

Comment: In not-so-near-future military SF, one sometimes sees dedicated boarding pods - basically a mobile airlock that seals itself against the hull of another ship, allowing an inner hatch to be opened and the target hull breached without major pressure drop. That kind of boarding action would have to be pretty commonplace for that pod to exist, though.

Comment: @Russell Borogove Sealing the mobile airlock alone would not help, you need to fix the airlock to the hull to hold the enormous force of air pressure inside this airlock. Some strong nuts and bolts to mount a flange or something similar.

Comment: You mean a shuttle as in a generic shuttle not yet developed or The shuttle, aka the american one that stopped flying (making it a near future alternate reality)

Comment: Solely concerning fictional topics.

Comment: As the question clearly states a purpose of research for a work of fiction, this question belongs on worldbuilding.

Comment: @Noah a question about pure fiction asking for answers about a fictitious space station is really off topic here. You could modify your question or ask a new one asking about one or more real station, and use that answer any way you like. For example, you could ask about the challenges that an emergency boarding pod would have including the attachment and the forces involved, then answers *with some basis in fact* could be given. Welcome to stackexchange! Take a look at how other questions are worded here, and while you are at it, [take the tour](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour)!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the Shuttle mission. If it's carrying an airlock, wait for someone to go out the hatch and then sneak in.